# where i can get the postman collection data in windows 10?

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

To clarify, I want to find where Postman saves collection files to by default when online syncing is disabled

I've looked in %LocalAppData%, My Documents, and Program Files, but I don't see where Postman saves its collection data

Comment: You can export your collection from the Postman settings menu, but that doesn't answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

you have to get the details form Roaming\Postman   not in  LocalAppData

Answer (score 0):

C:\Users\your username\AppData\Roaming\Postman\IndexedDB\